# Mongoose Reference for simple code reference values?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm designing a MongoDB schema to save a fairly large/nested document.  I'm planning on embedding as much as possible into a single document, but wasn't sure what to do with code/lookup values.  For example, if we have a code table representing "priority", with the possible values being:

- low
- medium
- high

Is this something I should use a Mongoose reference for, and create a simple document to hold priority, eg something like:

```
 var PrioritySchema = new Schema({
    description: String
 });
```

This would then be referenced with something like the following:

```
 var AnotherSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    active: Boolean,
    priority: { type: String, ref: 'Priority' }
 });
```

Or is this overkill?  The thing I want to avoid is directly storing these "descriptions" in the main/overall model, then having a requirement change sometime in the future.  For example, someone decides that instead of "medium", we need to call it "somewhat".  In that situation, I assume I'd be stuck doing some sort of data migration?

Comment: The question is too abstract, you should give some more details about how priority is going to be used and if there' any information regarding priority apart from the description. Hard to suggest something without knowing the specifics when it comes to modelling schemas.

Comment: added another schema to show how the priority would be used/referenced - please let me know if the example is still incomplete.  Thanks!

Comment: I just don't get the point of separating priority from main schema? You want to change it without changing main document? Or you use one priority in multiple documents?

Comment: If priority is just that predefined set of 3 values, then it's definitely overkill to separate it. The priority value only has meaning as part of the parent document and looks like just a simple property. Otherwise, you should give us more detail about the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this :

```
    var PrioritySchema = new Schema({
    description: String
 });
```

and this

```
var AnotherSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    active: Boolean,
    priority: { PrioritySchema  }
 });
```

But if you want what you described further I would advise you to do this instead :

```
var AnotherSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        active: Boolean,
        priority: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Priority' } // see this : Schema.Types.ObjectId != String
     });
```

Let's make it simple if you need those values to be cross-documents you need to use reference. If the values are only existing because of the parent document then you can choose embing.

For more information read this : 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html

FYI : I used to struggle a lot with this. If you follow the path of embing all nested sub-document you will face a lot of "What Why I can't do that :'(. At the end I choosed the referencing way I felt more confortable with it. embing != referencing.